# Simple Cocoa modal window dialog on Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, modal-dialog

I am porting a plug-in from 32-bit to 64-bit which is actually in C++. Since [Carbon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_%28API%29) is no longer supported on 64-bit, I have to port some code to [Cocoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_%28API%29). The only Cocoa help I need is how to create a simple modal window (not a sheet) that has two buttons, OK and Cancel, and gives me a string input from the user. I created a Cocoa nib, but have no clue with Objective-C. I could start learning Objective-C right now, but it takes a while and that's the only code snippet I need right now.

What would the code snippet look like?

Comment: If you are porting an application to Mac OS X, learning Obj-C is more or less required.  Yes, there are other ways to develop application for Mac OS, but Cocoa with Obj-C is the mainstream path.  

Also, why do you think you need a modal dialog instead of a sheet?  The Human Interface Guidelines generally suggest against using modal dialogs.

I think you're looking for a quick hack, but would be better served by learning how to use the underlying system.

Comment: Agreed. This way lay madness.

Comment: Hello,
I am porting a plugin which renders graphics inside a video application. That application doesn't support support sheets. I am not looking for a quick hack, but its more like I don't want to learn a new language just for one system level call. Atleast, it takes weeks if not months for me to learn Obj-C from scratch which will be past the deadline.

Comment: I don't mean that I don't want to learn Obj-C at all, but it makes more sense to get into it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's all you need, you may be able to avoid Cocoa by using CFUserNotification APIs instead.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that API at all. It has existed from 10.0! There are   so many APIs...

Comment: Hey! Great. It works great for my purpose. Just get the input string! Thanks a lot for that!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to learn some Objective-C and Cocoa regardless of what else you want to do, because there isn't "one system level call" to present a modal panel.

At minimum, you will need to create an NSWindowController subclass for your panel, which will act as File's Owner of its nib file and manage the interaction between its controls and whatever data it's manipulating.  Then you'll need to pass this to `-[NSApplication runModalForWindow:]` and handle the result, or to `-[NSApplication beginModalSessionForWindow:]` and handle running and/or stopping the modal session yourself.

This means writing coding against the Cocoa frameworks in Objective-C.

Fortunately, since you're just starting with a message, a text field, and a couple of buttons, this will be pretty easy.  But it's not just a matter of a hypothetical `NSGetTextInput()` function — Cocoa eschews such things in favor of abstractions that can be pieced together in straightforward and extensible ways.

For example, if you decide you don't just need text input but also a checkbox, you'd have to replace your hypothetical `NSGetTextInput()` with something like the above.  But by doing the above in the first place, adding that checkbox becomes a few seconds of extra work.  Or adding interesting validation to your text input.  Or pre-populating your text input with data from an object.  Or implementing a time-out (including presenting a countdown timer) on your modal dialog.  (Modality is strongly disfavored nowadays...)  Or any of a number of other changes.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I am really looking forward to learn Cocoa in detail, and this gives me a good intro.